Create procedural texture oriented toward light
I'm trying to create procedural texture in Blender (4.2) Eevee : some kind of hatching effect, and brushstrokes oriented toward light.
On the upper right corner, it's been done in photoshop with Palette Knife effect :
The closest result I could achieve so far is this one, but it doesn't work on the side of the cube, or when light is at the same height as the sphere.


The downside of this method is that it works only with one light.
Is it possible to achieve this kind of result with only lighting (intensity) information ?
Or is it at least possible to address the current problem ?

Blender File :

What you are trying to achieve is gobos, right ? You can simply plug a texture in your light shader as follows : https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/322460/62539

It almost works but it's centered where the vector light-plane aims (need to use a plane to cast textured shadow as I'm using eevee). Ideally, lines should be oriented to the maximum intensity on each surface.

I managed to orient lines toward lights, using light coordinates and object coordinates.
I rotate object coordinates toward light in geometry node, and plug it into cartesian to polar coord in shader editor:


It’s not perfect on round surfaces, but it already works pretty well. It’s possible to choose [object pivot to light] vector or nearest face normal to rotate the coordinates. You can play with it if you want :

